# How can I return a value from .then method of a promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

In the following javascript code snippet (written for nodejs), the createDoc function returns a promise. Upon fulfillment of the promise, the handler passed to .then is invoked. The question is that how can I make .then return doc? According to the documentation, .then returns a promise but I'm really looking for it to return doc.

```
 let p = createDoc(title).then(function (doc) {return doc;});

 //p is a promise, and not doc
 console.log(p);
```

What is the proper way to access the value passed to the fulfillment handler (doc in this case) **outside** the .then?

Comment: can you show the code for your createDoc function

Comment: In promise, you always get a promise in return. What you are going to do with `doc` - that will give some idea on how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

do something like this and when the promise resolves the value of doc will be inside p

```
let p;
createDoc(title).then(doc => p = doc);
```

Comment: @Nishant yeah but that's what he want, he wants the resolved value in p

Comment: And can you access p after createDoc

Answer (score 0):

You can use async-await, if you want to have the value instead of promise in p

```
async function someFunction() {
    ...
    let p = await createDoc(title);
     console.log(p);

    ...
}
```

What you are seeing is a behavior of promises calling chaining.